# $count++ on every time submit button pressed

Tags: php

```
<body>
<?php
                            $count=0;
                            if(isset($_POST["show"]))
                            {
                                $count++;
                                echo $count;
                                unset($_POST["show"]);
//sql query for show record limit ($count*$row_per_page),$row_per_page
                            }
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="show" value="show more">
</form>
</body>
```

i want to increase variable's value on every time submit button clicked. 
actually i want show next 10 records on every submit button on same page.

Comment: Google: Pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a field for count and set a value using jquery and increase the value of count on button and submit the form using jquery. Change the input to button and make the type of button = button

```
 <body>
 <form action="index.php" method="post">
 <input type='hidden' id='count' value="<?php echo $count;? >">
 <button type="button" name="show" value="show more">Show More </button>
 </form>

 <script>
  $(document).on('ready', function ()  {
     $('[name=button]').click(function () {
       $('#count').val($('#count').val() + 1);
       $(form).submit();
     }):

    });
   </script>
   </body>
```